# Rank of a matrix must be less than 1003?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in M_{2006}(\Bbb F)$ be a matrix, $U \subseteq \Bbb F^{2006}$ the row space of $A$ and $W \subseteq \Bbb F^{2006}$ the coloumn space of A. 
Suppose $U \oplus W = \Bbb F^{2006}$, and let $B \in M_{2006}(\Bbb F)$ be a matrix such that $A \cdot B= 0$.

Prove that $rank(B) \le  1003$.

I understand why it's true, and yet I can't find a way to write a formal proof. First I understood that $rank(A) = 1003$, but I'm kind of stuck from here, any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Your notation is pretty confusing. For me. $\;A\in M_n(F)\iff A\;$ is a **square** matrix of order $\;n\;$ , and thus both the row and columns spaces are contained in $\;F^n\;$ .

Comment: I fixed the question. does it make sense now?

Comment: Yes, now it does, yet the claim fails without further info. For example, what if $\;A=0\;$ ? Then we could have rank$\,B=2006\;$ , say with $\;B=I\;$ ...

Comment: In my answer below, I interpreted your condition as just $U + W = F^{2006}$.

Answer (score 0):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\rank}{rank}$Since $A B = 0$, the image of $B$ is contained in the kernel of $A$, so that by [rank-nullity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem)
$$
\rank(B) \le 2006 - \rank(A) = 2006 - \dim(W),
$$
or
$$
\dim(W) \le 2006 - \rank(B).
$$
But then, looking at transposed matrices, we have $B^{\top} A^{\top} = 0$, so that the image of $A^{\top}$ is contained in the kernel of $B^{\top}$, and thus
$$
\dim(U) = \rank(A) \le 2006 - \rank(B).
$$
The condition $U + W = F^{2006}$ tells you that $\dim(U) + \dim(W) \ge 2006$.
You get
$$
2006 \le \dim(U) + \dim(W)
\le 2 \cdot (2006 - \rank(B)),
$$
and there you are.

Comment: In this answer, I interpreted your condition as just $U + W = F^{2006}$.

Answer (score 0):

By the row space of $A$ you probably mean the column space of $A^T$, otherwise it can be in the same space as the column space of $A$.

I'll denote by $C(A)$ the column space of $A$, so your setting can be stated as $C(A^T)\oplus C(A)=V$, where $V=F^{2n}$, being $A$ and $B$ matrices in $M_{2n}(F)$.

The rank of $A$ is the same as the rank of $A^T$, so both $C(A)$ and $C(A^T)$ have dimension $n$.

Since $AB=0$, you have $C(B)\subseteq N(A)$ (the null space of $A$). This means
$$
\dim C(B)\le\dim N(A)=2n-n=n
$$